# How to show the navigation overview when launching Google Maps intent with a location in an Android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Related to this problem are 3 standard Google Maps views:

1. Shows a centered marker on a 2D map from above, has a button to open Navigation
2. Shows the navigation route on a 2D map from above
3. Shows the turn-by-turn navigation using some kind of 3D map and playing sound (if on)

I want to open view 2 from my app (so the user quickly can see the route and if in need of turn-by-turn navigation just needs 1 tap), but I only seem to be able to open view 1 or 3. View 1 has the drawback of only centering the destination and view 3 has the drawback of being annoying (3D mode, voice) if the user just wanted a quick overview, as well as requiring 3 taps on BACK to get back to my app.

View 1 is opened by this code:

```
String format = String.format("geo:0,0?q=%s,%s(%s)", destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, destinationName);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(format);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

View 3 is opened by this code:

```
String format = String.format("google.navigation:q=%s,%s", destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(format);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

How to open view 2?